# Cannot get image when using onsubmit in form instead of onchange

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit

I want to upload an image, my code was set up so that when I open the image it immediately sends an XMLHttpRequest and the image got uploaded.

Now I need to change this around and use an additional button with the type of `submit` instead. However once I do that the image seems to no longer load correctly.

This is the form:

```
<form id="profileImgForm">                      
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Finalize Upload">
</form>
```

and this is the JavaScript that works, using `onchange` as the method:

```
var imgfile = "";

document.getElementById("profileImgForm").onchange = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    if(e.target.files.length > 0) {
        imgfile = e.target.files[0];
    }
}
```

This works, but what I need it to do is react to `onsubmit`. However if I change it to `onsubmit` the image file is not found any more.

I open the image in the `fileToUpload` input and then I click on the submit button. However now I get an error like `cannot read property 'length' of undefined`, which means the image file cannot be found for some reason.

Why might this not work any more when using `onsubmit`, and how can I get the image file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the onchange, e.target is the file input element, but for the onsubmit, e.target is the entire form.  You could use `e.target[0].files[0]` or get the file input element by its id.